# Heated comments about reinstalling - Call for moderation

Tags: support, moderation

I got a flagged answer for review of deletion: https://askubuntu.com/a/779533/75166

The answer includes a description how to reinstall Ubuntu for a question that might be solvable with other means. A heated discussion between a commenter criticizing the answer and the OP and the OA enrolled.

Could someone with more moderation-skill (than I) please help out and defuse the situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can flag comments too.

Put your mouse over a comment and a little flag will show on the left, flag one with a custom reason, explain about the whole thread and a mod will be alerted.

There is not much us normal users can do, we would just get pulled in to the argument, as we have no privileges to  remove the comment(s).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. That's what I did now.